# how do I force a field to be translated in my Odoo code?

Tags: odoo, translation, v8

I am developing a module for electronic invoicing, and should express the payment term in spanish, so I am setting a dictionary with all the needed fields, and when I do this:

```
{
...
'FmaPago': inv.payment_term.name,
...
}
```

The output file contains the value "name" in english. I've tried something like

```
_(inv.payment_term.name)
```

but with the same result.

How should I force the value to be expressed in a defined translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field name of Payment Terms are already translatable. You can change the translation in Odoo by clicking the little button within a field in edit mode.

[image: Translatable field in Odoo]

If you've done that correct, you have to avoid some typical mistakes at code side if you use the old API.

1. always pass the context

e.g. if you browse the invoice, pass the context, to get all translations correct

2. use partner language if you want to translate for them

Odoo is using user language in his context, to translate the web client correctly. If you print documents for customers, you want them in customer language of course...
So you maybe need to manipulate the context (key 'lang'). For new API you have to call with_context() to do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must use _() for strings that you want to be able to translate.
2. You must make translating files *.po (as i remmember) and thats all I think.

Dont forget to check documentation [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/translations.html)